# Extracting all the ID's whose sum of values is greater than another value

Tags: sql, teradata

i have an output table like this -

[image]

In here, i want to get all the ID's whose sum of amount is greater or equal to 40 & order by date. I tried using having condition but it isn't working. This is what i used -HAVING sum(a.amount) >= 40

What can i do to get this done?

Comment: It looks all applications has only one record in the table is not it?

Comment: Your sample data only has one row per `application_id`, so it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Which *sum of amout*  of which *IDs*? Which rows should be returned based on your example data and why?

Answer (score 0):

Try using subquery:

```
select tablename.* from tablename
inner join
(select id, sum(amount) from tablename
group by id
having sum(amount)>=40)a
tablename.id=a.id
order by appl_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You seems want window function :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(amount) over (partition by appl_date, valid_from) as totalamount
      from table t
     ) t
where totalamount >= 40;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that "id" means `application_id` and that your table has multiple rows for a given `application_id`, then you can just use aggregation and `having`.

It is unclear what you mean by "order by date", but you can do:

```
select application_id, sum(amount)
from t
group by application_id
having sum(amount) >= 40
order by min(appl_date) asc;
```